# how split elements of ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have `ArrayList`. I need split each element of this ArrayList by "," and as result got  `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. How to do it properly?
This is code I have tried:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
   try {
    ArrayList<String> lines = rf.readLines(filename);         
        for (int i = 0; i<=lines.size(); i++){
            String[] items = lines.get(i).split(",");
        }
    }  
    catch(IOException e)  
    {   
        System.out.println("Unable to create "+filename+": "+e.getMessage());                
    }
```

Comment: so what is the problem or error ?

Comment: Now you only need to move the `String[]` into an `ArrayList<String>`. You can use the [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method to continue solving your problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear - I lost your meaning at "...as as result got ArrayList>." You do not define what you mean by "do it properly".  Expand, let us know if you're getting an error and what it is, be sure to define the output you want.

Comment: You should go only to `i < lines.size()`, not `<=`

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the `line` array into an `ArrayList` and add that to `list`.  This should do the trick.

```
list.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items)));
```

Comment: Yep. Or he could also build an `ArrayList<List<String>>`, and directly store the result of `Arrays.asList(items)`.